# Why is gnuplot failing with "Unknown device: pngalpha"?

Tags: png, gnuplot

I'm running gnuplot on RH7 through a perl script using the Chart::Gnuplot per module.
The perl version is 5.8.8.
The gnuplot version is a bit less obvious, but $VERSION in Gnuplot.pm is set equal to '0.23' (although I get the same results with ver 3.2)

Anyway, When I run this on RH6, it works fine.  RH7 is a problem.  The error is...
Unknown device: pngalpha

I tried different versions of gnuplot.pm with no success.  But from googling around, I think the problem may reside in a utility (a different install) that gnuplot is using to generate png formatted output. I suspect there's something lacking in the RH7 env for that.

Does anyone know what gnuplot uses to translate it's native graphic format to png ?

Comment: The "unknown device" error message was not from gnuplot; it has never has such an error message.  I would guess your script did not get as far as actually calling gnuplot. It may have failed to find some configuration script needed by the perl module.

Comment: My suspicion is that the error message came from gs which gnuplot used to generate the png.  More searching last night indicated that on the RH6 side, the pngalpha device IS supported in gs while it is not on the RH7 side.  And googling indicates that the error message is something gs may generate.

Comment: gnuplot does not use gs or any other utility to generate png output.  Depending on which output terminal is requested it uses library calls into either libgd or libcairo and creates the png output file directly.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this isn't what you asked, but nevertheless I suggest it as a way forward.

Having now looked at the documentation and issues tracker for the perl module  Graphics::Chart::Gnuplot, my take is that it is both too old and too narrowly focused on a limited set of gnuplot capabilities to be worth fixing or working around the limitations.  You can see issues of inadequate png support that are still active on the tracker from 7 years ago.

I have done a fair amount of perl coding using gnuplot for graphics. Early on I looked into custom modules like the one you mention, but I soon found that it was much preferable to simply open a pipe to gnuplot and send the commands directly.  I append below a simple example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# open pipe to gnuplot and set terminal type
        my $gnuplot = "/usr/local/bin/gnuplot";
        open(GNUPLOT, "|$gnuplot") or die "can't find gnuplot";
        binmode GNUPLOT,":encoding(UTF-8)";
        my $outfile = $ARGV[0];

# send some simple commands one at a time
        print GNUPLOT "set term pngcairo font 'arial,10' size 600,400\n";
        print GNUPLOT "set output '$outfile'\n";

# send a block of commands
print GNUPLOT <<EOFgnu;
        set title 'Example of gnuplot from perl'
        sinc(x) = (x==0) ? 1.0 : sin(x) / x
        plot sinc(x) with lines linecolor 'blue' linewidth 3
EOFgnu

# That's it. We're done.
        close GNUPLOT;
```

And here is the file created by `perl example.pl foo.png`

[image]